# Combine contents of two rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine two rows into one data cell. It might be that I don't know the correct keyword to look for, but I've tried stack, unstack, merge, groupby, pivot, melt, merge, join, concatenate. These operations all seem to work on entire dataframes, but leave each cell as an individual cell. Can you point me in the right direction? Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
Key    Data
___    ____
 A       1        
 A       2
 A       3
 B       4
 B       5
 B       6 
 C       7
 C       8
 C       9
```

needs to be converted to:

```
Key    Data
____   ____
 A       1 /r/n 2 /r/n 3
 B       4 /r/n 5 /r/n 6
 C       7 /r/n 8 /r/n 9
```

Comment: try `df['Data'] = df['Data'].astype(str)` and then 
`df = df.groupby('Key')['Data'].agg(' /r/n '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I was so close, yet so far.